# Sharepoint Change List's "web address"

Tags: sharepoint, list

When I click the Settings|Document Library Settings menu the page that appears for my list has this at the top:

```
List Information
Name: Wisdom
Web Address: http://<our intranet>/wisdom/forms/allpages.aspx
Description:
```

How do I change the "Web Address" to `http://<our intranet>/wisdom/home.aspx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web address for the list is its Default View. So if you create a view called "home.aspx" and set it as the default, you could change it to `http://<our intranet>/wisdom/forms/home.aspx`. Now, a Document Library differs from other lists, mostly since it stores documents. It stores its Views in the Forms directory, along with all of the forms like EditForm.aspx and DispForm.aspx. There is no standard means to allow a Document Library to use a view that is stored in somewhere besides Forms, meaning you can't get rid of /forms/ being in your Web Address. In exchange, though, document libraries don't have to deal with having /Lists/ in the front.

Meanwhile, the actual document tree of that library will be stored in the root. `http://<our intranet>/wisdom/home.aspx` would point to a home.aspx that is stored in your document library. So you could, in theory, add a copy of default view's aspx into the document library. Since the address `http://<our intranet>/wisdom/home.aspx` will actually open the aspx file in your browser, it'd be no different than navigating to it. However, you would have said file as a part of your document library, and it would not affect the "Web Address" listing on your list settings.

To summarize: You can't change that particular listing like that. At best, you can change allpages.aspx to home.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple.

1. Type in the direct path to the list and click on "List Settings".
2. Create a temporary view and set it as the default.
3. Go back and select the previous or original view and reset it to the default view.

This will fix the bad web address to point to the proper location of the list.